# Would this sentence mean the same if we removed one of the negatives: "How can't you not like this tune?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

**"How can't you not like this tune?"**

I understand the sentence means "it is almost impossible not to like this tune. Everybody likes it." And the structure of the sentence with two negatives seems to emphasize the impossibility of not liking the tune. I see this usage sometimes, although I am not sure if this is just colloquial usage.

However, I noticed that without two negatives, the sentence would still mean the same. Or at least this is what I think. Let's compare:

**"How can't you not like this tune?"**

**"How can you not like this tune"?**

They more or less mean the same to me, but I am not sure. So, I wonder if we have to use the 1st structure to mean the impossibility of not liking the tune? Or do we not need it since the second sentence structure is enough to refer to that impossibility of not liking it.?

Comment: A *dedundant* negative? Such as [What does "there ain't no one for to give you no pain" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102982/what-does-there-aint-no-one-for-to-give-you-no-pain-mean)

Comment: Related on ELU site: [Are double negatives ever appropriate in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31667/are-double-negatives-ever-appropriate-in-english)

Comment: *How can't you not like this tune?* is a very unusual, non-standard phrasing, and sounds wrong to me.  Did you see this used somewhere, by a native speaker?

Comment: *How can't you...* is probably unusual enough that there can be no consensus on what it means.  Either it was a mistake, or it's part of an idiolect or a dialect that's so small only the speakers themselves could tell you what it means.

Comment: @stangdon, most of where I have seen used this type of usage is social media. However, some people above mention that "double negatives" are standard English. For instance "When I see someone in trouble, I can't not help." If this is an example of double-negative, it sounds perfectly fine. So, how is this different from the sentence "How can't you not like this tune"? Isn't this also a double-negative question?

Comment: @Juhasz Thanks for the answer. I didn't know that "How can't you ...." is unusual enough. I thought "how" is just another question word like "why, when, etc". So, in that case I wonder if using "can't" with other question words also unusual? For example Would it also sound unusual if I said "Why can't you lose weight"? or "When can't you sleep?" or "What can't you do if you are ill?"

Comment: "I can't not help" means "It is impossible for me to do other than help", which is logical. "How can you not like it?" means "How is it possible for you to dislike it?" Negating that - "How is it impossible for you to dislike it?" - doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok I understand "how is it impossible for you to dislike it" does not make sense in English, although it does in my native language. So, I am thinking about how to mean the same thing in English. If you listened to a tune which is so good, and you think whoever listens to it will like it." or "You think It is impossible for everyone to resist such a good tune." So, is there a way to say this so strongly emphasizing your certainty that there can't be anyone who won't like the tune and that you would be astonished if you see such a person. Can I say "How impossible it is to not like the tune?"

Answer (score 2):

The first structure is more or less meaningless.  I've tried reading it slowly and trying to work out what it means by logic. I've tried reading it quickly and hoping that "intuition" will suggest a meaning - both attempts failed. I think it would never be used intentionally.

The second "How can you.." sentence is fine.  The idiom "How can you" expresses incredulity at a statement, action or belief of another.

Comment: I have read about "double-negatives". For instance "When I see someone in trouble, I can't not help." If this is an example of double-negative, it sounds perfectly fine. So, how is this different from the sentence "How can't you not like this tune"? Isn't this also a double-negative question?

Comment: Because "How can you" is an idiom, It doesn't work in the negative.